# Passing Data Context from Dynamic Template as Autoform Name

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

So I have list of data context and successfully generated lists of data needed from Meteor Dynamic Template.
But I need a clean way to put it dynamically inside autoform,

**This is not working**, only generated some fields without label text and other properties of autoform paramter.

```
{{#each this.items}}
{{> afQuickField name="{{fieldName}}"}}
{{/each}}
```

But, if I try non-dynamically, it's still working,

```
{{> afQuickField name="customerName"}}
```

I try to check the data from data context, still ok,

```
{{#each this.items}}
{{fieldName}}
{{/each}}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `name=this` else `name=fieldname` instead of `name="{{fieldname}}"`

Comment: Did you try both options ??

Comment: I didn't see the else option, and that's working, thank you, I'll mark it as answered, can you tell me why it didn't need the double parentheses?

Comment: If we give Parentheses ,it assumes as string .we don't need parentheses for helpers